# Replace gksudo with pkexec using a individual message

Tags: ubuntu, debian, root, gksudo

My GUI will started as an user. There is an update-mechanism in the program, which calls a wrapper-script with root rights. For that i used **gksudo**, until i realized, that it is replaced by **pkexec**.

If i just replaced gksudo by pkexec it works quite fine. But i want to have an own message to the user. Therefore i have to modify or generate a xml-policy file in */usr/share/polkit-1/actions*

My problem is, when i call

```
pkexec <my-program>
```

I'll get this prompt, which refers in *Details-->Action* to **org.freedesktop.policykit.exec**.

[image]

Do i have to place an **action id**-entry to this xml-file (**org.freedesktop.policykit.exec**) or do i have to create my own .policy file named **com.myStuff.updater.policy** into */usr/share/polkit-1/actions*?

```
  <vendor>myStuff</vendor>
  <vendor_url>http://myStuff.com</vendor_url>
  <icon_name>myStuff</icon_name>

  <action id="com.myStuff.updater">
    <description>My description</description>
    <message>My message</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_self_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="com.myStuff.updater.exec.path">/my/path/to/wrapper.sh</annotate>
    <annotate key="com.myStuff.updater.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
  </action>
```

Or should i call my whole application in my **.desktop**-file with *pkexec*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest creating your own `.policy` file and leave `org.freedesktop.policykit.exec` alone, for several reasons:

- `pkexec` does not work as expected under certain circunstances, in Terminal, in `.desktop` files, etc. This is actually a Gnome bug about double-fork.
- With your own `.policy` file you edit it at will and even configure it for password-less root privileges for your script! And that's a very interesting feature!
- You could invoke your script simply using its *name*, as any other command, no need to prepend it with `pkexec` or `sudo` or anything so it would work anywhere.

You may use `gparted`'s policy file as a template.